# URL Scheme launched program has some features blocked by Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4, url, url-scheme

I have a link in an asp.net mvc 5 page that references a custom URL scheme.  The executable launches just fine.  The program does access the internet and when launched from Chrome the video feature will not connect.  It works fine in IE.  Basically the executable is a WinForms app that uses Vidyo for video conferencing.  I can also simply double click the app and it works fine.  My question is why would an executable launched from Chrome (via URL scheme) have features blocked?  What security account does Chrome use?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between IE and Chrome is that in IE, there is a Vidyo plugin that is being used, whereas in Chrome there is no plugin and would use WebRTC for video streaming.

Comment: Thanks for the response.   I actually got this to work by commenting out a line of code in the vidyo .net sample about a certificate.  Amazing that removing that line made the .exe launch from Chrome!